# OOM in Apache Spark: how can I understand if it is in Driver or in Executor?

Tags: apache-spark

From time to time Spark jobs may fail with OutOfMemory exception. I want to have some general rule to understand where the issue has happened: on driver or on executor. How can I elaborate one?

Please check my ideas:

1. If OOM is logged in driver logs, but all executors in Spark UI showed no failed tasks - this looks like driver issue. If same error can be found in Spark UI - it has executor nature.
2. Discriminate by packages and classnames. As we known on executors Spark runs some generated code. Driver's code is just Java/Scala with normal class names.
3. Find SparkContext class in StackTrace. SparkContext only exists in Driver.

What is your advice?

Comment: Idea 1 should be enough, I would say. Do you have an example of a stack trace where it is not clear if the OOM occured in  the driver or the executor?

Comment: @werner, actually I faced issue which falls under first category. But I am sure there can be much more situations.